# Angular material icon mat-icon is not displaying correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating Navigation drawer in my angular 4 app using angular-material.
Initially, I am creating a toolbar to have header and menu button(mat-icon is menu)

Here is my code,

```
<mat-toolbar class="example-header" color="primary">
    <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
<span class="header-name">Hello</span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

But I am getting the output as follows,

[image]

But I wanted output something like this,

[image]

The difference in the output is, the mat-icon button has grey background whereas the required doesn't.
Please correct me.

The app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { GoogleMapsAPIWrapper } from '@agm/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import 'hammerjs';
import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatDrawer, MatDrawerContainer, MatDrawerContent,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule,

  MatStepperModule,
  MATERIAL_SANITY_CHECKS
} from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
  providers: [GoogleMapsAPIWrapper],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: For `MatDrawer`, just import `MatDrawerModule`. **Don't** import the internal component.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your `app.module.ts`, you forgot to import `MatButtonModule` into your module. (By the way, you shouldn't import every single module if you don't even use it. It's a bad idea!)

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule
    // ...
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, got the mistake

Comment: Please help me here, when i create both toolbar and sideNav main content are getting overlapped? `<mat-toolbar >
        <button  mat-button  mat-icon-button><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
    <span class="header-name">Hello</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container>
        <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened="false">
            <span>Dashboard</span><br/>
            <span>Incidents</span><br/>
            <span>Users</span>
            </mat-sidenav>
            <mat-sidenav-content>
               Content
            </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>`

Comment: Downvoter, could you explain why you downvoted the question?

Comment: @Anil That's because your `<mat-toolbar>` is out of the `<mat-sidenav-content>` element. The `<mat-sidenav-content>` element is used for all elements that are **not** in the sidenav.